# Image bigger than the screen

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio, imageview

I think I have a simple question, but after a few hours I still can't manage it.

I have an image which fits into screen height, but it's wider than the available space.
I would like to animate this image.
It's something like this:

[image: paralaxa try]

As of now, I made an animation by using the translate component in animation.xml file.
But when I'm animating this ImageView - it's cut.
Everything which is bigger than the screen is deleted.

Is ImageView the right component to store images like this?
Or maybe should I use other View and setting the image as background?

The animation will repeat forever including reverse - I managed it out already, but is Translation the best choice for that issue?

I need to animate 2 images to make something like a parallax effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found solution. The case was: parrent of component had match_parent wich is full screen ( and nothing more ). ImageView was cliped to parent size. I solved it by adding ScrollView as parent, and disabling scroll function by adding onTouchListener:

```
    sView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is for sure not nice method to solve it - but it worked.